# ReactDOM.render signature

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

In ReactJs to render tag, we usually use below code in the script tag

```
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Here the 2nd argument is valid JS, but what is the 1st argument? What does 1st argument represents (function, variable)?

and what purpose `babel` serve here? would it create an object of App Class under the hood and replace it?

Comment: It's JXS (you are not forced to use it although it's highly recommended).
You must transpile it to be usable in a browser.

Comment: @Keul Any ideas what it will be compiled to?

Comment: See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects)

Comment: You can see what it compiles to [here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=EoUwhgxgLgIg8gWQHQCcQDsAmIUAoA8AggA7EAEA9AHwA0ZmA9hAK4C2GUSA5iFAKIAbEO3RQAQgE8AkplwByFAwZQ5ASlUBuIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react%2Cenv&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.3.4)

Answer (score 1):

It's a React (JSX) component. This will be transpiled successfully if you have

```
import React from 'react';
```

at the top of your code. This means it will be converted to a normal JS class/function (depending on how you've written your component).

It looks like this just to make React easier to write and think about. The transpiled code will be some native Javascript that the React framework uses to render your code. You won't need to understand it fully unless you want to change how the React framework itself works.

Underneath the hood all the React `<Components>` are just functions or classes with render methods, really.

[edit: You will have a dependency on Babel as part of your bundling process, as this is what does the transpiling. However, since you should be using create-react-app or something similar to make the skelton of your app, this will be handled for you invisibly at this stage. If you want to start getting clever, however, you will need to get a basic understanding of a bundler (like Webpack/Gulp/Parcel) and Babel.]

Answer (score 0):

First Argument is JSX element which is later transpiled to vanilla javascript.